# In Reflection, Method object's parameter class doesn't match argument class?

Tags: java, class, reflection

[This post has been edited to include a simplified copy/paste version of the underlying issue.]

I'm working on a Reflection project that will have some functionality similar to JUnit, but I'm running into an obstacle where the program seems to feel I have 2 different versions of the same class.

I've written a simple Car class as follows.

```
public class Car {
    private String name;

    public Car(String n) {
        name = n;
        System.out.println(name + " was constructed.");
    }

    public void honk() {
        System.out.println("beep beep");
    }

    public void crash(Car other) {
        System.out.println(name + " crashes into " + other.name);
    }
}
```

I can successfully test the functionality of the car like this:

```
public class CarRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car a = new Car("Model T");
        Car b = new Car("Tesla");
        a.honk();                 //prints "beep beep" 
        a.crash(b);               //prints "Model T crashes into Tesla"
    }
}
```

All the stuff above works fine.

Now, I want to reproduce the results of CarRuner but with some functionality testing methods I've written using reflection.  Using reflection, I can request the creation of object and invoking methods with those objects.  It works great until the final test, when a user-defined class is used as an argument.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TesterTool {    
    //Where are the class files that I am testing?
    private static File classPath = new File("C:\\Users\\Spatter\\Desktop\\Autograder\\SimpleCarDemo"); 

    public static Object makeObject(String nameOfClass, Object[] arguments) {
        Object retObject = null; //goal is to get an object in here of the requested class.
        try {      
            //What type of object are we trying to construct?
            URL classUrl = classPath.toURI().toURL();
            URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{classUrl});
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(nameOfClass, true, classLoader);           

            //What kind of arguments do we have?
            Class[] argumentTypes = new Class[arguments.length];            
            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                argumentTypes[i] = arguments[i].getClass();
            }

            //Lets find a constructor that can accept the type of arguments we have
            Constructor con = c.getConstructor(argumentTypes);                          

            FutureTask<?>  theTask = new FutureTask<Object>(new Callable<Object>() 
                    {
                        public Object call() {
                            Object retObject = null;                            
                            try {                                    
                                retObject = con.newInstance(arguments);
                            } catch (Exception e) { return e; }
                            return retObject;
                        }
                    });

            ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            es.execute(theTask);
            retObject = theTask.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            es.shutdownNow();
            if (retObject instanceof Exception) throw new Exception();                         

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error: Unable to construct object" + e);                   
        }
        return retObject;
    }

    public static Object testMethod(Object invokingObject, String methodName, Object[] arguments) {
        Object retObject = null; //if the method we test returns an object, we will do the same.
        try {   

            //What type of object are we trying to construct?           
            Class c = invokingObject.getClass(); 

            //Alternate version of getting class type using ClassLoader         
            //Class originalc = invokingObject.getClass();     
            //String nameOfClass = originalc.getName();            
            //URL classUrl = classPath.toURI().toURL();
            //URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{classUrl});
            //Class<?> c = Class.forName(nameOfClass, true, classLoader); 

            //What kind of arguments do we have?
            Class[] argumentTypes = new Class[arguments.length];            
            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                argumentTypes[i] = arguments[i].getClass();
            }

            //Lets find a method that can accept the type of arguments we have
            Method m = c.getMethod(methodName, argumentTypes);                          

            FutureTask<?>  theTask = new FutureTask<Object>(new Callable<Object>() 
                    {
                        public Object call() {
                            Object retObject = null;                            
                            try {                                    
                                retObject = m.invoke(invokingObject, arguments);
                            } catch (Exception e) { return e; }
                            return retObject;
                        }
                    });

            ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            es.execute(theTask);
            retObject = theTask.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            es.shutdownNow();
            if (retObject instanceof Exception) throw new Exception();                         

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error: Unable to run method " + e);                   
        }
        return retObject;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Find the Car class and invoke the constructor that receives a String parameter.
        Object o1 = makeObject("Car", new Object[]{"Model T"});      //this works fine.
        Object o2 = makeObject("Car", new Object[]{"Tesla"});        //this works fine.

        //Invoke the honk method of object o1.  No parameters required.
        //The result is that "beep beep" is printed.
        testMethod(o1, "honk", new Object[] {});                     //this works fine.

        //Invoke the crash(Car c) method of o1 using o2 as the parameter.
        //This should print "Model T crashes into Tesla".
        testMethod(o1, "crash", new Object[] {o2});          //this doesn't work.
    }
}
```

This last test is where my problem is coming into play.  testMethod appears to be unable to find a version of the crash method that matches my request.  The crash method is supposed to receive a Car object, which it does, but it doesn't seem to be good enough.

I've also tried a very complex alternate version of this where I get all the methods of the Car class and try to find one that matches the signature, but it seems to feel that an object of Class car isn't an object of Class car.  (See below.)

```
Class objectClass  = o2.getClass();
Class[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes(); //where method is the Method object for crash
Class paramClass = paramTypes[0]; //there was only 1 paramType.  I confirmed that it's the Car class.
System.out.println(objectClass); //prints class Car
System.out.println(paramClass); //prints class Car
if (paramClass.isAssignableFrom(objectClass)) {      //always returns false?
    System.out.println("I want to run this method because the signature matches.");
    // o1 should invoke method using FutureTask
}
```

isAssignableFrom() always returns false, even though they are both Car classes.  Any idea what might be the problem?  I've inspected the both of the Class objects (objectClass and paramClass) and they appear to be identical, even down to the paths in the ClassLoaders.

Instead of isAssignableFrom(), I've also tried isInstance, but it didn't work either:

```
if (paramClass.isInstance(o2)) {      //also always returns false
```

Comment: Can you share your code (in a minimal, working example) so people can recreate?

Comment: Don't write test code that you need to test, or ask questions about here. Keep it simple, keep it repetitive if necessary, keep it obvious,

Comment: First off, never use the default package.  If the code listing above (and the assertions in the comments) is faithful you have two different classes loaded named "Car" in the default package.  Are you messing around with classloaders perhaps?  Check that `objectClass.getClassLoader() == paramClass.getClassLoader()`

Comment: Also post your `testMethod()`.

Comment: Yes, I am using ClassLoaders, as the class files I am testing are not in the working directory (and never will be) of the program running the tests.  I will make a streamlined version of my program so people can recreate the issue.

Comment: You should reuse the URLClassLoader.

Comment: Thank you @JohannesKuhn and BadZen. My understanding of URLClassLoaders was limited and that was exactly the problem.  By only creating one URLClassLoader object as a static variable everything seems to be fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from creating a new URLClassLoader object each time I was locating a Class object.  By having only 1 URLClassLoader as a static variable the issue is resolved.